# npm: find out which dependencies use a given package (indirectly)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm currently working on a node.js-project and I've been keeping up with the most recent node releases during development. Now that node 6 is out, I wanted to see if I could make that decision as well.

It turns out some of the modules I use are dependent on older versions of `graceful-fs` which doesn't support node 6. I get warnings when installing and executing my application, but I can't determine where the `graceful-fs` package is being used (indirectly).

How can I find out?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I am fairly certain this is what you want:

`npm ls graceful-fs`

[See documentation here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

Comment: I think this question refers to find which package are using a sub dependency. I think the op was looking for npm-explain that is available since v7 https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-explain or with yarn-why https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why/

Answer (score 9):

Copying from @Soufiane Ghzal's comment and the npm-ls docs:

> To get a "bottoms up" view of why a given package is included in the tree at all, use `npm explain`.

Comment: `npm ls xxx` is a lot simpler to visualise, but thank you for adding this one. I'm in the middle of upgrading a massive project and was looking for the level of detail that npm explain shows (specifically the expected versions)